# When redirecting top to a file, why does cat command on that file display output of multiple top attempts?

Tags: linux, io-redirection, cat, top

I am customizing a Linux system with a kernel of 6.4.0, and I have noticed a strange issue. When I execute `top > a.txt` and then open a window to execute `cat a.txt`, I find that the `cat a.txt` result is the result of multiple `top` attempts, but I wouldn't have this problem with other Linux systems. In other Linux systems, the `cat` command only displays the results of the `top` command once. I don't know why?

```
# top > a.txt
# cat a.txt
# ls /usr/bin/top -ltr
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000            17 Aug 23 02:34 /usr/bin/top -> ../../bin/busybox
```

add `top type`:

```
# type top
top is /usr/bin/top
```

Comment: try `top -n 1`, since `top` command runs until you quit it - or until `-n` iterations are run

Comment: @JaromandaX  Sorry, this can only solve surface problems. I want to know the root cause?

Comment: the root cause is that `top` keeps outputting until you hit `q` ... unless you specify the number of loops ... are you saying that `top > a.txt` just stops by itself? how long before it stops?

Comment: @JaromandaX My question is why in my customized system, the result of `cat a.txt` is the result of many `top` commands, but in other Linux systems, the result of `cat a.txt` is only the result of one `top` command.

Comment: so is it just `top` that behaves in this odd way? `echo a > a.txt; echo b > a.txt` displays just `b`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Just only `b` in `a.txt`.I used `cyclictest` and the same goes for it.

Comment: "_the result of cat a.txt is the result of many top commands_" - no, it's the result of one command with many iterations. That's a really important difference

Comment: @ABeginner  A lot of progress reporting code works by continually over-writing the last line on the terminal, using a CR (Carriage Return) code. If you send that to a file, it comes out as one extremely long line, which on Unix would break some commands. But anything that uses terminal control codes or ncurses to write updates to a formatted window can have similar effects.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Some `top` implementation (e.g. on OpenBSD, but presumably on some Linux systems too) detects whether its output is going to the terminal or to something that isn't a terminal (to a pipe or to a file) and changes its behaviour depending on this.  If the output goes to a terminal, the utility will be in interactive mode, accepting input from the user and regularly updating its display. When the output goes elsewhere, then `top` runs in non-interactive mode and will, by default, just output one "screen" of results and then quit.

The `top` implementation included in Busybox does not do this and will continue to output screen updates even when output goes into a file or pipe.  Each update will be preceded by a control character sequence that clears the screen, so `cat` should show you the final screen update (unless the terminal is not interpreting the control characters), while if you open the file in an editor or use `less` to view its content, you may see several consecutive screen updates.  This also seems to be the case for the `procps-ng` variant of `top` sometimes found on Linux systems.

If you want Busybox's `top` only to output a single screen of output to a file, use

```bash
top -n 1 >file
```

As to *why* this is so, it just comes down to the developers of the various `top` implementations having implemented the tool differently.  If you want further information about the decisions taken while implementing the `top` utility in Busybox, you may want to ask in a Busybox-specific forum or mailing list.